# Trim middle digits in mysql?

Tags: mysql, trim

I have a 29 digit field called **ahl_tin** and it is a VARCHAR(255).

How to trim the 22nd and 23rd digit from it in mysql

thanks

Comment: Is there any example input and output that you would like to share into the question ?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty example for ahl_tin,**ahl_tin=11320900100010000000300026003**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LEFT` and `RIGHT` functions to trim the text and combine those two with `CONCAT` function.

**Query**

```
SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(ahl_tin,21),RIGHT(ahl_tin,6)) AS trimmed
FROM tbl;
```

**[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f9158/4)**

Comment: Welcome. If this solved your problem, please mark it as answer.